# Email Server to run sql query on a postgresql attached to django

Tags: django, email, django-rest-framework, office365

I'll give some information about my setup although it may be somewhat arbitrary to the question.

I'm using django and django-rest-framework hosted on heroku as the backend to a flutter app. I'm using the heroku postgres add-on for the database.

My objective is to set up user email validation system but in a way that is slighty unconventional for reasons I wont get into.

I'd like to have users send an email to a specified adress, and on every email that comes in run a simple update sql query to set that user as active. No assistance is needed with the query.

I'm looking for suggestions for an email server that might make this possible. If I can use the django ORM to do this, even better, but not neccesary.

I've been looking into vba on outlook, but office 365 pushes alot of features at cost that I'm not interested in. If you could point me in the right direction of making a vba macro to get the job done that would be great, but other ideas are welcome.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why not have someone click a link in the email that activates the user? Receiving and parsing emails can be done, but it is a much more complex setup to achieve. Also, please post example code wherever possible to demonstrate what you have and are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to have the inbound emails routed to a service like Mailgun, Mandrill, Postmark, etc. Those services have the ability to translate an inbound email into a request made to a webhook on your application. So you can treat an inbound email as a web request. A good Django library for handling this across a number of those providers is [anymail](https://anymail.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Once you have that webhook setup, you'll have access to your normal Django application and ORM. That should allow you to do what you want.

From [anymail's receiving mail docs](https://anymail.readthedocs.io/en/stable/inbound/):

```
from anymail.signals import inbound
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(inbound)  # add weak=False if inside some other function/class
def handle_inbound(sender, event, esp_name, **kwargs):
    message = event.message
    print("Received message from %s (envelope sender %s) with subject '%s'" % (
          message.from_email, message.envelope_sender, message.subject))
```